# Bouding the state using the reward in RL

Tags: reinforcement-learning, reward-functions

I'm wondering what the common approaches are bounding out state $s\in\mathbf{R}$ to some values $\in[s_0,s_1]$ is required. So in my case, for example, the state represents an angle of rotation, that should Ideally be bounded between $0$ to $\pi$ radians. My naive approach to enforce that was to check the state in every `step`, and "*punish*" when the state is not contained in this range. With respect to this approach - how the "*punishment*" should actually be implemented? Two options I thought of are:

- if $s_t\notin[0,\pi]$: $r_t \leftarrow 0.1$ - This, in my opinion, may not be optimal as there is no indication of how far are we from $[0,\pi]$. Also, there is no incremental aspect - Even if we diverged from $[0,\pi]$ once or 1000 times, the reward is always the same.
- if $s_t\notin[0,\pi]$: $r_t \leftarrow 0.9\cdot r_t$ - the longer we stay outside the needed range, the reward tends to zero, but still It doesnt count for distances

Any other common ideas?

Comment: Since you are working with an angle, did you consider simply [unwrapping the angle](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unwrap.html)? For example, we know that a rotation of $3\pi$ radians is equivalent to a rotation of $\pi$.

Comment: My desired goal would be to learn a reciprocating motion, so I don't think that unwrapping is good here. If the angle is $3\pi$ that means full rotations which I'm trying to avoid. (Think of a robot with wings that should learn how to fly where $s=\phi$ is the angle of wing rotation)

Comment: I don't really understand the question. The state is not an output of your agent, but comes from the environment, which is not something you train. The action, the state value (a function of the state), or the action state value (a function of the state and the action) are, so these could be constrained in some bounds by penalising the agent, but not the value of the state itself.

Comment: @RaphaelLopezKaufman I can define the reward to penalize unwanted states so the agent will try to avoid them as they do not contribute to the maximization of the reward

Comment: Ah I see, is there a particular reason why you don't want to use a negative reward? Your examples are both positive rewards.

Comment: Hmm not really - do you have any suggestion on how this should be implemented? I did try, for example $r_t \leftarrow r_t -1$, with no luck